# Xamarin Forms - trigger code on change of an image source

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How can I trigger a method on the change of an image source?

I have a custom image inheriting from a cached image, when I change the source I want to trigger a method to check if the source is in local storage or in the app resources.

The bit missing is triggering the method, sorry I don't have code to post but I haven't started the trigger code yet, here is the XAMl for the image.

```
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="bigImg" CacheType="Memory" />
```

Comment: just subscribe to the PropertyChanged event

Comment: ah ok, got it thanks

Comment: works great, if you want to put it as an answer I'll accept as it's helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just subscribe to your VM's `PropertyChanged` event, and if the property is "PreviewImage" then call your method.